# How does an array terminate?

Tags: c

As we know a string terminates with `'\0'`. 
It's because to know the compiler that string ended, or to secure from garbage values.

But how does an array terminate?
If `'\0'` is used it will take it as `0` a valid integer,
So how does the compiler knows the array ended?

Comment: Short answer - it doesn't, except possibly in the scope of the original array declaration. What are you asking about, exactly?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  For a string literal, the compiler creates an array of `char` and initializes it with the characters from the literal and adds a trailing null byte to mark the end.  For other arrays of characters, it is the programmer’s job to ensure that there is a null byte at or before the end of the array if it is to be treated as a string.  For arrays of other types, the onus is on the programmer to know how long the array is.

Comment: At compile time, compiler knows the length of the array (and can be accessed with `sizeof` operator). It is not known at run time, unless you yourself store it to a variable for example. What might be confusing is, you can't really pass arrays as function parameters. They are converted to pointers, even if the syntax in function parameter list looks like an array. So if you need the length of array given as function parameter, you have to pass it as an extra parameter (or use some other method, like 0 byte in strings).

Comment: Not only in 'C' Lang .  Every string is ended with "\0". But why array doesn't need that termination.

Comment: @user11784338 imagine you have an array of integers. Which value should be used to "terminate" the array?

Comment: @Jabberwocky that's what my question? If "\0" is taken it take it as 0 a valid number. Why we are not terminating is the reason : Contiguous memory allocation

Comment: @CarlNorum  How array will be terminated like String? First plz say me about why String need to be terminated?

Comment: @user11784338 an array cannot be "terminated" by a special value. If you "terminate" an array of integers with some special value (e.g. 0) then you could not store 0 in the array. Strings on the other hand are a very special kind of array, they are terminated by 0 by definition.

Answer (score 7):

C does not perform bounds checking on arrays.  That's part of what makes it fast.  However that also means it's up to you to ensure you don't read or write past the end of an array.  So the language will allow you to do something like this:

```
int arr[5];
arr[10] = 4;
```

But if you do, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  So you need to keep track of how large an array is yourself and ensure you don't go past the end.

Note that this also applies to character arrays, which can be treated as a string if it contains a sequence of characters terminated by a null byte.  So this is a string:

```
char str[10] = "hello";
```

And so is this:

```
char str[5] = { 'h', 'i', 0, 0, 0 };
```

But this is not:

```
char str[5] = "hello";  // no space for the null terminator.
```

Answer (score 3):

C doesn't provide any protections or guarantees to you about 'knowing the array is ended.' That's on you as the programmer to keep in mind in order to avoid accessing memory outside your array.

Comment: Not at all sink with my question

Answer (score 3):

C language does not have native string type. In C, **strings are actually one-dimensional array of characters terminated by a null character `'\0'`**.

From C Standard#7.1.1p1 *[emphasis mine]*

> **A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character**. The term multibyte string is sometimes used instead to emphasize special processing given to multibyte characters contained in the string or to avoid confusion with a wide string. A pointer to a string is a pointer to its initial (lowest addressed) character. **The length of a string is the number of bytes preceding the null character and the value of a string is the sequence of the values of the contained characters, in order.**

*String* is a special case of character array which is terminated by a null character `'\0'`. All the standard library string related functions read the input string based on this rule i.e. read until first null character.

There is no significance of null character `'\0'` in array of any type apart from character array in C.

So, apart from string, for all other types of array, programmer is suppose to explicitly keep the track of number of elements in the array.

Also, note that, first null character (`'\0'`) is the indication of string termination but it is not stopping you to read beyond it.

Consider this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[5] = {'H', 'i', '\0', 'z'};
    printf ("%s\n", str);
    printf ("%c\n", str[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

When you print the string

```
printf ("%s\n", str);
```

the output you will get is - `Hi`

because with `%s` format specifier, `printf()` writes every byte up to and not including the first null terminator *[note the use of null character in the strings]*, but you can also print the 4<sup>th</sup> character of array as it is within the range of `char` array `str` though beyond first `'\0'` character

```
printf ("%c\n", str[3]);
```

the output you will get is - `z`

**Additional:**
Trying to access array beyond its size lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which includes the program may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.

Comment: Array is also a contiguous of integers/float. But array cannot be terminated.And why string needs termination? Not an array.

Comment: @SWAROOP read the answer carefully. I have already given its answer.

Comment: @SWAROOP *And why string needs termination?*  It's defined that way so the end of the string can be found without having to pass the length around with the string.  Why don't arrays in general need termination?  Because that's **your** job as a programmer - you need to know how big **your** arrays are - notice how functions such as `memcpy()` require **you** to specify how many bytes to copy?

Answer (score 0):

**It’s just a matter of convention.** If you wanted to, you could totally write code that handled array termination (for arrays of any type) via some sentinel value. Here’s an example that does just that, arbitrarily using -1 as the sentinel:

```
int length(int arr[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; arr[i] != -1; i++) {}
    return i;
}
```

However, this is obviously utterly unpractical: You couldn’t use -1 in the array any longer.

By contrast, for C strings the sentinel value `'\0'` is less problematic because it’s expected that normal test won’t contain this character. This assumption is *kind of* valid. But even so there are obviously many strings which *do* contain `'\0'` as a valid character, and null-termination is therefore by no means universal.

One very common alternative is to store strings in a struct that looks something like this:

```
struct string {
    unsigned int length;
    char *buffer;
}
```

That is, we explicitly store a length alongside a buffer. This buffer isn’t null-terminated (although in practice it often has an *additional* terminal `'\0'` byte for compatibility with C functions).

Anyway, the answer boils down to: For C strings, null termination is a convenient convention. But it is *only a convention*, enforced by the C string functions (and by the C string literal syntax). You could use a similar convention for other array types but it would be prohibitively impractical. This is why other conventions developed for arrays. Notably, **most functions that deal with arrays expect both an array and a *length* parameter**. This length parameter determines where the array terminates.